# how to dynamically insert datediff into webpage to keep updated in real time (now)

Tags: php, sql, datediff

I can do a request in phpmyadmin to show the number of days between todays date and a date selected by a user:
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), `date_instructed`) AS DAYS FROM date_tester

.. but i think this wont update all the table and will only update when a new record is created in the table.

So can anyone suggest the best way  to dynamically update/count  the days in a column by using a date entered by a user .

Should it even be put in a column? or should i use php to echo the result for each row on the webpage.

If I should be manipulating the ‘date_instructed’ with a script and then entering it in the html table seperatly is their a link to show me how to do this?

Many thanks

```
<?php
include 'dbh.php';
?>
<table class="table table-sm table table-bordered 
  table table-hover table table-striped  "> <!--, table table-inverse-->
  <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <tr class="warning">
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last</th>
      <th>Date Instructed</th>
      <th>Days On Market</th>
    </tr>      
  </thead>

    <?php

    $query  = "SELECT  first_name, last_name, date_instructed , days_onmarket 
                FROM date_tester";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while ($date_tester = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $date_tester['first_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $date_tester['last_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $date_tester['date_instructed'] . "</td>";
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: `Should it even be put in a column? ` = No. Don't try to store this as a column, it has to be computed every day. You can do this as a sql query or as a sql view or you could do it in PHP. Just don't store it.

Comment: You can do the date arithmetic in a sql query, and it just  becomes another column to output. Im not a PHP person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand this is what you need:

```
 $query  = "SELECT  first_name, last_name, date_instructed ,    days_onmarket, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), 'date_instructed') AS DAYS FROM date_tester";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while ($date_tester = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $date_tester['first_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $date_tester['last_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $date_tester['date_instructed'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $date_tester['DAYS'] . "</td>";
}
```

Comment: i not a fan of books for coding, i learned in college, but there is a course from Zend for begginners